# java.lang.NullPointerException while running my applet

Tags: java, mysql, applet

i am trying to make some mysql table insert operation but i am finding this java.lang.NullPointerException when i input fro my applet, couldnt figure out where i am wrong in this code can u plz help me! i tried doing database operation without applets with this same part of code it worked

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class StudentEntry extends Applet implements ActionListener {
/**
* 
*/
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
Label l1,l2,l3,l4;
TextField t1,t2,t3,t4;
Button b1;
public void init(){
Label l1=new Label("Enter your Name : ");
add(l1);
TextField t1=new TextField(20);
add(t1);
Label l2=new Label("Enter your Sem : ");
add(l2);
TextField t2=new TextField(20);
add(t2);
Label l3=new Label("Enter your Branch : ");
add(l3);
TextField t3=new TextField(20);
add(t3);
Label l4=new Label("Enter your Contact Number : ");
add(l4);
TextField t4=new TextField(20);
add(t4);
Button b1=new Button("Submit");
add(b1);
b1.addActionListener(this);
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
{
try
{  
String sname=t1.getText();
String semT=t2.getText();
int sem=Integer.parseInt(semT);
String branch=t3.getText();
String contact=t4.getText();
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Mice","root","1234");  
Statement stmt=con.createStatement(); 
String Uquery="Insert into StudentDetails(student_name,sem,branch,student_con)values('"+sname+"',"+sem+",'"+branch+"','"+contact+"')";
int val=stmt.executeUpdate(Uquery);  
if(val==1)
{
System.out.println("succesfull inserted");
}
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from StudentDetails");  
while(rs.next())  
System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+"  "+rs.getString(2)+"  "+rs.getInt(3)+"  "+rs.getString(4)+"  "+rs.getString(5));  
con.close();  
}
catch(Exception e)
{ 
System.out.println(e);
}  
}
```

//end of code

Comment: In which line do you get the NPE?

Comment: while collecting input from text field in actionPerformed

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

1) please change the System.out.println(e); in the catch statement into e.printStackTrace(); , you may find where you went wrong...

2) for the NullPointerException, your init() function does not really initialized your "TextField t1,t2,t3,t4;", please using this.t1 to exchange for TextField t1 in the init function.